# Is it possible to integrate Selenium IDE tests ( saved in .side file) with jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, selenium-ide

I made a couple of auto-tests on the web application using Selenium IDE, but selenium IDE saves tests as .side file. Is it possible tests saved as .side file integrate into jenkins and do the job in jenkins to run for example once a week?Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the Selenium web driver for Jenkins... Check out this [tutorial](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/integration-of-jenkins-with-selenium-webdriver/)

If you need more specific help with Jenkins configuration for scheduling there is a lot of documentation for that you can google for.

Answer (score 0):

run .side file via [selenium-side-runner](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner) command-line runner

```
$ selenium-side-runner /path/to/your-project.side
```

you might need to meet some dependencies, all well explained in the [link](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner).